# Как правильно переопределить метод what() в собственном классе исключений?

Tags: c++, переопределение, виртуальная-функция, override

Нужно создать класс исключений, в котором переопределить виртуальную функцию what(). Компилятор выдает следующее сообщение: "объявленная с использованием ключевого слова Override функция-член не переопределяет член базового класса".

```
class incompatible_dim_exception : public std::exception
{
private:
    const char* name;
public:
    incompatible_dim_exception(const char* m_name) : name(m_name){};
    const char* what() override{
        return name;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте переопределить ее так, как указано в стандарте:

```
const char* what() const noexcept override;
```

Answer (score 2):

Укажите правильное определение:

```
const char* what() const noexcept override {
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае правильнее будет не переопределять `what`, а наследовать от `std::runtime_error`, которая из коробки поддерживает хранение и отдачу некоторого текста. Также это позволит избавиться от проблем с потенциальныv протуханием буфера, на который указывает `m_name`:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class incompatible_dim_exception : public ::std::runtime_error
{
public: explicit
    incompatible_dim_exception(char const * const psz_name) : runtime_error{psz_name}{}
};
```

Comment: В задании нужно было именно переопределить, но спасибо за подсказку на будущее)

Comment: А почему `explicit` на строке с `public:`?

Comment: @вася ну я обычно использую стиль - название с новой строки, то бишь спецификаторы доступа, атрибуты и т.п. - на одной строке, а название новой сущности - на следующей. Таким образом названия оказываются выровнены по вертикали, что доказано улучшает читаемость

Comment: @user7860670 в таком случае логичней кажется 3 строки: `public:`, `explicit` и название, потому что `public:` для всех следующих спецификатор, а `explicit` только для одной. Или вы для каждой сущности указываете спецификатор доступа отдельно?

Comment: @вася Да, спецификатор доступа указываю каждый раз. Это позволяет записывать элементы в логическом порядке, а не в соответствии со спецификатором доступа, также изменения спецификатора у одной сущности не влечет ее переноса или добавления еще одного спецификатора для далее идущих сущностей и т.п. Собственно многие (все?) более новые объектно-ориентированные языки делают именно так

Comment: @user7860670 интересный стиль, спасибо за объяснение